# Recycler view spacing with picasso

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-recyclerview, picasso

I am trying to build something like a gallery, like [this](https://lh3.ggpht.com/sBpXAxbwO4OXywXcVmTc2ADg0FHyDzSPEQWiS1V4KAms22Oo6mXSaqKMDmltYr6L4w=h900).

To do that, I used `RecyclerView` and `LayoutManager`.

First I created a custom layout to hold my image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I created a custom `Adapter`, there I set the `Picasso` to download the image on each row:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PhotosForPlantsAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    String urlFoto = photos.get(i).getPath();
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/" + urlFoto;

    viewHolder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .resize(240, 120)
            .centerInside()
            .into(viewHolder.img);
}
```

the result i get is this:

[image]

I want to center the row, and not have that big space at the end, and the image seem not to be thumbnail with fixed size like (100x100) or (20x20) how can i achieve that??

```
**Acitivity code:**


package com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Adapters.PhotosForPlantsAdapter;
import com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Adapters.SimiliarPlantsAdapter;
import com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.interfaces.IResult;
import com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.models.Photo;
import com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.models.Plant;
import com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.services.VolleyService;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FotosForPlant extends AppCompatActivity implements IResult {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<Photo>();

    VolleyService mVolleyService;
    IResult mResultCallback = null;
    final String GETREQUEST = "GETCALL";
    PhotosForPlantsAdapter adapter;
    String token;

    Double latitude = null;
    Double longitude = null;
    Double altitude = null;

    String time = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fotos_for_plant);

        String id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("plantId");

        Log.d("responseId",getIntent().getExtras().getString("plantId"));

        final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/fotos/" + id + "/plants";

        Log.d("resposta",URL);
        getFotosForPlantVolleyCallback();

        mVolleyService = new VolleyService(mResultCallback,this);

        checkForToken();
        mVolleyService.getDataVolley(GETREQUEST,URL,token);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),5);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new PhotosForPlantsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), photos);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    void getFotosForPlantVolleyCallback(){
        mResultCallback = new IResult() {
            @Override
            public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONObject response) {
            }

            @Override
            public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONArray response) {
                Photo photo;
                Log.d("resposta","HEYYY1");
                // iterate over the JSONArray response
                for (int i=0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i); // get the individual object from JSONArray
                        Log.d("objeto",object.toString());
                        int id = Integer.parseInt(object.getString("id")); // get the unique identifier from the object
                        if(latitude != null && longitude != null && altitude != null){
                            latitude = Double.parseDouble(object.getString("lat"));
                            longitude = Double.parseDouble(object.getString("lon"));
                            altitude = Double.parseDouble(object.getString("altitude"));
                        }
                        time = object.getString("date");
                        String path = object.getString("image");
                        photo = new Photo(path,id,latitude,longitude,altitude,time); // construct the object
                        photos.add(photo); // add the object to the arraylist so it can be used on the cardLayout


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void notifyError(String requestType, VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("resposta",error.toString());
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONObject response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONArray response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyError(String requestType, VolleyError error) {

    }

    public void checkForToken(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("user",MODE_PRIVATE);
        String tokenKey = getResources().getString(R.string.token);
        if(sharedPref.contains(tokenKey)){ // check if a tokena already exist on sharedPreferences
            token = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.token), tokenKey); // take the token
        }
    }
}
```

**layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.FotosForPlant">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="387dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="5dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: put your activity layout  and code here

Comment: done, see it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public final class SquareImageView extends ImageView {


public SquareImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
}
}
```

And

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="5dp" />
```

These lines will fix your problem and make your views looks like thumbnail. Also make sure you resize it as square while loading with picasso or glide. (whatever you use)

**Usage** `

```
<LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="#FFFFFF"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <your.package.whereverclass.SquareImageView
         android:id="@+id/img"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_margin="2dp"/>
</LinearLayout>`
```

Answer (score -1):

GridLayoutManager gives each item same width by default. You gave each image a fixed width and as a result have what you have.

I do not know the sizes of your images but if you change .resize(240,120) to .resize(0,120) you should get desired result.

also your RecyclerView's width and height should be match_parent.